# Navigation Drawer error

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a problem with my app. 
Program says:

```
"error: no suitable method found for replace(int,android.app.Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument android.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.Fragment by method invocation conversion)"
```

I dont know what i can do with it.

Comment: Source code will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've imported the wrong type of Fragment in the class.  You need to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: You're welcome .. it happens to me all the time and it's so frustrating that the support library classes are identically named to the native classes.